# Domain driven design database validation in model layer

Tags: database, uml, domain-driven-design, modeling

I'm creating a design for a Twitter application to practice DDD. My domain model looks like this:

[image]

The user and tweet are marked blue to indicate them being a aggregate root. Between the user and the tweet I want a bounded context, each will run in their respective microservice (auth and tweet). 
To reference which user has created a tweet, but not run into a self-referencing loop, I have created the UserInfo object. The UserInfo object is created via events when a new user is created. It stores only the information the Tweet microservice will need of the user.

When I create a tweet I only provide the userid and relevant fields to the tweet, with that user id I want to be able to retrieve the UserInfo object, via id reference, to use it in the various child objects, such as Mentions and Poster.

The issue I run into is the persistance, at first glance I thought "Just provide the UserInfo object in the tweet constructor and it's done, all the child aggregates have access to it". But it's a bit harder on the Mention class, since the Mention will contain a dynamic username like so: "@anyuser". To validate if anyuser exists as a UserInfo object I need to query the database. However, I don't know who is mentioned before the tweet's content has been parsed, and that logic resides in the domain model itself and is called as a result of using the tweets constructor. Without this logic, no mentions are extracted so nothing can "yet" be validated.

If I cannot validate it before creating the tweet, because I need the extraction logic, and I cannot use the database repository inside the domain model layer, how can I validate the mentions properly?

Comment: Would be better with some code, as in where are you running into problems? What language are you writing this in? How far down the DDD track are you? (NB. aka it depends -  DDD (Domain Driven Development) - IDDDD :D

Comment: Ps. Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: What are these non-navigable aggregates at all??

Comment: What is `UserInfo` (in contrast to `User`)?

Comment: UserInfo is a reference object, because each tweet / mention etc. must have a reference to user, but I want to keep more data then just the id. And since User will live in a seperate microservice, I've chosen to use a UserInfo object as a reference to the User in the tweet microservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever an AR needs to reach out of it's own boundary to gather data there's two main solutions:

1. You pass in a service to the AR's method which allows it to perform the resolution. The service interface is defined in the domain, but most likely implemented in the infrastructure layer.

   e.g. `someAr.someMethod(args, someServiceImpl)`

   Note that if the data is required at construction time you may want to introduce a factory that takes a dependency on the service interface, performs the validation and returns an instance of the AR.

   e.g.

   ```
    tweetFactory = new TweetFactory(new SqlUserInfoLookupService(...));
    tweet = tweetFactory.create(...);
   ```
2. You resolve the dependencies in the application layer first, then pass the required data. Note that the application layer could take a dependency onto a domain service in order to perform some reverse resolutions first.

   e.g.

   If the application layer would like to resolve the `UserInfo` for all mentions, but can't because it doesn't know how to parse mentions within the text it could always rely on a domain service or value object to perform that task first, then resolve the `UserInfo` dependencies and provide them to the `Tweet` AR. Be cautious here not to leak too much logic in the application layer though. If the orchestration logic becomes intertwined with business logic you may want to extract such use case processing logic in a domain service.

Finally, note that any data validated outside the boundary of an AR is always considered stale. The `@xyz` user could currently exist, but not exist anymore (e.g. deactivated) 1ms after the tweet was sent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think this hits the sweet spot I'm looking for. I will look into the factory pattern in ddd with domain services!